# Does Storage Spaces Direct require stored credentials and/or delegating credentials?

Tags: storage, windows-authentication, vdi

So I'm trying to set up a highly available VDI environment. My initial configuration had two Hyper-V host servers and one server acting as a file share for centralized VM storage.

I recently found that my company applies a GPO that prevents both storing credentials in Windows Credential Manager as well as delegating any credentials to other servers. This means that we can not use the SMB file share that I created for this purpose (CredSSP is ineffective because credentials can't be stored). My request to remove this GPO has been denied.

I've been trying to find other storage solutions that aren't impacted by this "second hop" issue and still provide high availability, but it's proving to be difficult to find a definitive answer about authentication requirements. Most research has lead me to articles discussing hardware purchasing tips and SMB options, both of which are not what I'm looking for.

Storage Spaces Direct seems like a solution that we could use, but I cannot seem to figure out if it requires credential storage/delegation. Can anyone enlighten me about this? Our servers already have several physical disks configured with RAID; it would be a lot of effort to restructure our storage for this implementation only to find that we have another credential blocker.

Is Storage Spaces Direct a viable option? Are there other storage options that avoid this second hop issue and still provide high availability that I am missing? Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.